# Array unique values PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to find the Unique values by username:

so the resulting array would be `[0] =>JakeP, [1]=>TomC`

My code currently works, but I was wondering is there a better way to accomplish this task with less loops, or `using array_unique` function?

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 3
                [Username] => TomC
                [Project_Name] => Inventory
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 4
                [Username] => JakeP
                [Project_Name] => Inventory
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [Username] => TomC
                [Project_Name] => Stocks

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [Username] => Tomc
                [Project_Name] => Stocks
            )

    )
```

My code which works is :

```
$names_filter = array();
foreach($latest_projects as $project)
{
if(empty($names_filter)) 
{ 
$names_filter[] = $project['Username']; 
}
else {
foreach($names_filter as $key=>$value)
 { 
 if($value == $project['Username'])
   { break; }
 else
   {
    $names_filter[] = $project['Username'];
   }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to simplify your code. Example:

```
$names_filter = array();

foreach($latest_projects as $project)
{
    if(!in_array($project['Username'], $names_filter))
    {
        $names_filter[] = $project['Username'];
    }
}
```

The `in_array()` function checks for the existence of a value in an array. So the `foreach` loop will only add a project username to the $names_filter array if it's not in the array. The output should be a list of unique usernames in the $names_filter array.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP >= 5.5 you can take advantage of the array_column() function:

```
$uniqueNames = array_unique(
    array_column($myArray, 'Username')
);
```

Prior to PHP 5.5, you can use:

```
$uniqueNames = array_unique(
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return $value['Username'];
        },
        $myArray
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can loop through `$latest_projects` and store each user name to new array (`$filter`). Since array can't have two elements with same keys, if the key exists it will be overwritten.

```
$filter = array();
foreach ($latest_projects  as $project) 
{
    $filter[$project['Username']] = 1;    
}

$filter = array_keys($filter);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the performance of this over other solutions, but a similar effect can be achieved with the use of [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).  It's not as readable either though, which is just as important.

```
$uniqueUsers = array_unique(array_map(function ($p) { return $p['Username']; }, $latest_projects));
```